# Bootable device not recognised when connected to a USB 3.1 port

Tags: windows, boot, usb, ssd, bios

I have an external SSD that I'm trying to boot Hackintosh(macOS) on my laptop Acer Aspire 7 A715-75G but the SSD or any other device that I connect like USB its not recognised. But if I connected it to a 2.0 USB port then is recognised and everything works perfectly. The 3.1 ports are working perfectly once Windows or Hackintosh(macOS) starts but in the bios they are not. I have also tried the C-type port and its not recognising that one as well. So it looks like I'm stuck using the 2.0 port and not that it's not working but the speed is very slow like watching a 1080p live stream lags.

My SSD is Samsung EVO 860
and here is the External Rack [Mediacom](https://www.mediacomeurope.it/prodotto/M-HDSB3AS/box-esterno-hdd-25-sata-usb-30)

Comment: Probably only solvable by Acer. Check whether there's any BIOS/UEFI update available.

Comment: Booting Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware is brushing up against intellectual property law in much of the world.  This might not be strictly illegal but is certainly a grey area in law.  Don't expect much in assistance on a publicly viewable forum like this.